# Parsing dictionary entries with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to pull data from Jim Breen's WWWJDIC. The raw data returned has a lot of information delimited in several different formats.

The data pulled in the example below is from here:
http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi?1ZUJ%E5%85%88%E7%94%9F

先生 [せんせい] /(n) (1) teacher/master/doctor/(suf) (2) with names of teachers, etc. as an honorific/(P)/

Should I use a regex?

Answer (score 0):

Regex could work here; the data seems to be returned in a simple "headword [kana] /definition/" format, where definition can also contain slashes.  You should be aware that certain entries will omit "[kana]" (try searching for ハンバーグ for example.

Also, you should know the raw dictionary file that WWWJDIC uses is also available for download here: http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/edict.html. It may possibly fit your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved with a regular expression. This possible solution iterates over `entries` to produce an array of hashes:

```
dictionary = entries.map do |entry|
  entry.scan(/(.*) \[(.*)\] \/(.*)\//).map do |(headword, kana, definition)|
    { headword: headword, kana: kana, definition: definition }
  end
end
```

This is rather straightforward: scan each entry for three sections in a standard format, and map these matches into hashes by extracting the variables in an array into new names. If there is a simpler or clearer way to solve the problem than this, then you should use it, but otherwise I recommend something like this.

Note: Due to the use of foreign encoding in your data, this may not work unless you alter the encoding of the regular expression engine.